# Capistrano Migrate To Two Databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

I recently added a second database to my development Rails site, and made a custom rake task, 'SysConfig:db:migrate' which can be seen below:

```
namespace :SysConfig do

  task :set_custom_db_config_paths do
    ENV['SCHEMA'] = 'db_sysconfig/schema.rb'
    Rails.application.config.paths['db'] = ['db_sysconfig']
    Rails.application.config.paths['db/migrate'] = ['db_sysconfig/migrate']
    Rails.application.config.paths['db/seeds'] = ['db_sysconfig/seeds.rb']
    Rails.application.config.paths['config/database'] = ['config/database_sysconfig.yml']
  end

  namespace :db do
    task :migrate => :set_custom_db_config_paths do
      Rake::Task["db:migrate"].invoke
    end

    ...

  end
end
```

This takes all the migrations in the db_sysconfig/migrate folder and deploys them to the SysConfig database. However, I am struggling to work out how to set up this task in the deploy.rb file for Capistrano, for when I deploy to staging/production. Does anyone know how I can set the application config paths in capistrano?

Capistrano '2.15.4'
Rails '4.0.2'
Ruby '2.1.0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a new task to the deploy namespace in the deploy.rb file:

```
namespace :deploy do
  ...
  task :SysConfig, roles: :app do
    run "cd #{current_path}; RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} rake SysConfig:db:migrate"
  end
end

after "deploy:migrate", "deploy:SysConfig"
```

I then set it to run after the deploy:migrate task had been ran, which caused it to successfully migrate to both databases at the same time.